counting the number of success after certain date every year in Pandas using groupby cumsum
I have a data frame that looks like
Date            Student_ID  Exam_Score
2020-12-24      1           79
2020-12-24      3           100
2020-12-24      4           88
2021-01-19      1           100
2021-01-19      2           100
2021-01-19      3           99
2021-01-19      4           72
2022-09-30      3           100
2022-09-30      2           100
2022-09-30      1           100
2022-09-30      5           46
2023-04-23      3           100
2023-04-23      2           97
2023-04-23      1           100
2024-07-19      2           89  
2024-07-19      1           100
2024-07-19      4           93
2024-07-19      3           100
2024-09-19      1           100 
2024-09-19      2           80
2024-09-19      3           100
2024-09-19      4           80
2024-10-20      1           80
2024-10-20      3           99
2024-10-20      2           80

And I would like to compute a new column called Recent_Full_Marks which uses the following logic: for each Student_ID, compute the number of times that student getting 100 marks on the exam before the current date and after the Sept-1 one year before. So for example, on 2024-11-22, Student 1 has gotten 2 full marks before 2024-11-22 and after 2024-09-01. And the desired column looks like:
Date            Student_ID  Exam_Score      Recent_Full_Marks
2020-12-24      1           79              0
2020-12-24      3           100             0
2020-12-24      4           88              0
2021-01-19      1           100             0
2021-01-19      2           100             0
2021-01-19      3           99              1
2021-01-19      4           72              0
2022-09-30      3           100             0
2022-09-30      2           100             0
2022-09-30      1           100             0
2022-09-30      5           46              0
2023-11-23      3           100             0
2023-11-23      2           97              0
2023-11-23      1           100             0
2024-07-19      2           89              0
2024-07-19      1           100             1
2024-07-19      4           93              0
2024-07-19      3           100             1
2024-09-19      1           100             0
2024-09-19      2           80              0
2024-09-19      3           100             0
2024-09-19      4           80              0
2024-10-20      1           100             1
2024-10-20      3           99              1
2024-10-20      2           80              0
2024-11-22      1           70              2
2024-11-22      3           100             1
2024-11-22      2           78              0

Here is what I have tried:
Date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
full = (df.assign(Date=Date)
              .sort_values(['Student_ID','Date'], ascending=[True,True])
              ['Exam_Score'].eq(100))
df['Recent_Full_Marks']=(full.groupby([df['Student_ID'], Date.dt.year], group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.shift(1, fill_value=0).cumsum()))

However, the above method only counts the number of full marks after every year start and not every sept-1 and I was unable to modify it to work.

Why does the desired column have different values for rows with the same student ID?

Your code has some curly quotes, which makes it invalid

You could use a yearly period that ends on AUG-31 (Y-AUG) and groupby.transform with shift+cumsum:
df['Recent_Full_Marks'] = (df
 .sort_values('Date')['Exam_Score'].eq(100).astype(int)
 .groupby([df['Student_ID'],
           pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('Y-AUG')])
 .transform(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
)

Output:
          Date  Student_ID  Exam_Score  Recent_Full_Marks
0   2020-12-24           1          79                  0
1   2020-12-24           3         100                  0
2   2020-12-24           4          88                  0
3   2021-01-19           1         100                  0
4   2021-01-19           2         100                  0
5   2021-01-19           3          99                  1
6   2021-01-19           4          72                  0
7   2022-09-30           3         100                  0
8   2022-09-30           2         100                  0
9   2022-09-30           1         100                  0
10  2022-09-30           5          46                  0
11  2023-11-23           3         100                  0
12  2023-11-23           2          97                  0
13  2023-11-23           1         100                  0
14  2024-07-19           2          89                  0
15  2024-07-19           1         100                  1
16  2024-07-19           4          93                  0
17  2024-07-19           3         100                  1
18  2024-09-19           1         100                  0
19  2024-09-19           2          80                  0
20  2024-09-19           3         100                  0
21  2024-09-19           4          80                  0
22  2024-10-20           1         100                  1
23  2024-10-20           3          99                  1
24  2024-10-20           2          80                  0
25  2024-11-22           1          70                  2
26  2024-11-22           3         100                  1
27  2024-11-22           2          78                  0

